# Flask dropdown list from python list

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to create a dropdown list with flask, here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from data_harvester import api_requests
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def dropdown():
    pools = ['test1', 'test2']
    return render_template('index.html', pools=pools)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

and:

```
<div>
  <select name="pools" method="GET" action="/">
    {% for pool in pools %}
    <option value= "{{pool}}" SELECTED>{{pool}}</option>"
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

The dropdown list is rendered but without any elements, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are redefining `@app.route('/')`, so that's the problem. `main_page` is likely being called and not `dropdown`.

Comment: @h0r53 you are right, thanks!